# C# Tic Tac Toe - Trying to iterate through list and set each element to X or O if value is 0 or 1

Tags: c#, arrays, tic-tac-toe

[UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ulpc.png)
I'm working on a Tic Tac Toe project that uses a two-dimensional int array to simulate the game board in memory. When the user clicks the New Game button, the application should step through the array, storing a random number in the range of 0 through 1 in each element.
The number 0 represents the letter O and the number 1 represents the letter X. The form should then be updated to display the game board. The application should display a message indicating whether player X or player O has won, or the game was a tie.

I created an array of the textboxes, and I'm trying to iterate through each element, and if A1 (value[0, 0]) has a value of 0, then A1.Text should be set equal to "O", and if A1 has a value of 1, A1.Text should be set equal to "X".

However, **my loop isn't looping through each item, instead it's setting all of my elements in the textBox array to either X or O.**

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Project_4
{
    public partial class TicTacToe : Form
    {
        public TicTacToe()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Initialize row and column count
        const int rowCount = 3;
        const int colCount = 3;

        // Generate random number
        Random random = new Random();

        // Create two-dimensional int array
        int[,] values = new int[rowCount, colCount];

        List<int> myList = new List<int>();


        private void newGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Run functions
            randomize();
            updateView();
        }


        private void randomize()
        {
            // Loop through values[row, col]
            for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
                {
                    values[row, col] = random.Next(0, 2);
                    // Console.WriteLine(values[row, col]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void updateView()
        {
            TextBox[] textBoxes = { A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3 };

            for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (values[row, col] == 0)
                        {
                            textBoxes[i].Text = "O";
                            Console.WriteLine(textBoxes[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textBoxes[i].Text = "X";
                            Console.WriteLine(textBoxes[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: think how many times that inner loop is being executed

Comment: you set all the boxes to row=0,col=0, then all to row=0, col=1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your `UpdateView` method you're looping through rows, then columns then controls. For every combination of `row` and `col` you're iterating through *all* of the controls. The result is that your controls all get a final value based on the final cell (`values[2,2]`).

Remove the inner control loop and either calculate the array index each time or or use an index variable that is incremented after each column in the inner loop. For example:

```
private void UpdateView()
{
    TextBox[] textBoxes = { A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3 };
    
    // Initialize the index here
    int index = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
        // Increment index after each column
        for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++, index++)
        {
            textBoxes[index].Text = values[row, col] == 0 ? "O" : "X";
            Console.WriteLine(textBoxes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could set up your `textBoxes` array to match the 2-dimensional layout of the `values` array and just use the `row` and `col` variables to index both. While we're at it, let's add a way to put an empty value in (anything not `0` or `1`):

```
private void UpdateView()
{
    TextBox[,] textBoxes = { { A1, A2, A3 }, { B1, B2, B3 }, { C1, C2, C3 } };
    
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
        {
            textBoxes[row, col].Text = values[row, col] switch
            {
                0 => "O",
                1 => "X",
                _ => ""
            };
            Console.WriteLine(textBoxes[row, col]);
        }
    }
}
```